# OSX how to drop packets randomly

Tags: mac-osx, packetloss

I am testing the resilience of one of our streaming applications to handle packet losses. On linux machines I normally use iptables to randomly drop packets like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

I need to test this on a server that is currently running OSX. Any ideas how to randomly drop packets on an OSX Server or Mac computer?

/Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is `dnctl`. To quote from the manpage:

```
 plr packet-loss-rate
       Packet loss rate.  Argument packet-loss-rate is a floating-point number between 0 and 1, with 0 meaning no loss, 1 meaning 100% loss.  The loss rate is internally repre-
       sented on 31 bits.
```

And:

> To drop random incoming IPv4 and IPv6 ICMP packets with a probability of 5%, create a pipe:

```
dnctl pipe 10 config plr 0.05
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me in the right direction, but as I haven't used dnctl and the related dummy net tools, it wasn't that wasn't straightforward to apply. It did help me solve the problem though, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Teun Vink to use dnctl works, but is a bit tweaky as it relies on a bit of other configuration. Looking into this tool, I found that [**Xcode**](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) has an extension called **Network Link Conditioner** that is more a GUI interface for this that works really great. See [here](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) for instructions.

For a scripted solution, Teun's is the way.

Thanks!